# geeting string responce of xml how to conver into php array

Tags: php, xml

here is may request

```
   $data1 ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <IDV>     
         <policy_start_date>21/12/2017</policy_start_date>     
         <vehicle_class_cd>45</vehicle_class_cd>     
         <RTOLocationCode>10416</RTOLocationCode>     
         <vehiclemodelcode>12474</vehiclemodelcode>     
         <manufacturer_code>27</manufacturer_code>     
         <purchaseregndate>21/12/2017</purchaseregndate>  
         <prev_policy_end_date>21/12/2016</prev_policy_end_date>
          <manufacturingyear>2014</manufacturingyear> 
    </IDV>';

   $url = "http://202.191.196.210/uat/onlineproducts/wscalculate/service.asmx/getIDV";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"str=" . $data1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $response;
```

in echo I am getting following response

```
 <IDV>
 <exshowroomPrice>710570</exshowroomPrice>
 <idv_amount>675042</idv_amount>
 <idv_amount_min>607537</idv_amount_min>
 <idv_amount_max>776298</idv_amount_max>
 <exshowroomPrice_min>639513</exshowroomPrice_min>
 <exshowroomPrice_max>817156</exshowroomPrice_max>
 <outputmessage></outputmessage>
 </IDV>
```

Now If I used

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response); 
print_r($xml);
```

I am getting following response

```
   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 710570675042607537776298639513817156 )
```

I want to extract

```
      <exshowroomPrice>710570</exshowroomPrice>
```

how to extract that one. please help me I tried lots of solution but It didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the code is complete and no more manipulation is done with `$xml`? The print should be an object with associated keys with its values: https://eval.in/927492

Comment: you can tried it your end i will provide you details  click on following link  https://asteriskcomputerclasses.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=XWjQomABAAA.1BxGDmv3zefNwD1OxqkT8zWkEULpbVCxujtB0YbePuMEvNMa5nczlTt_YYagbSvfVo_5tL7-2SDnCxPsvPUPVg.TsrW_oz6g9S4Dab_E6fwOg&postId=8289861437594885852&type=POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML your getting back seems a bit odd, but this is not unusual.  It seems to be putting the main content in quotes, which doesn't really matter, but it just looks odd.  Worse is the namespace it's trying to use should be more like a proper URL - `tempuri.org/` should be `http://tempuri.org/` or something like that.

Anyway - the following works with that (although displays a few warnings based on the namespace being relative).  The main thing is that the `<string>` element has a default namespace, so when you load the data, you need to take this into account.  So what I've done is once I've loaded it, I get the children (`<IDV>` etc) using this namespace.  Then the resultant SimpleXMLElement can be accessed as normal.

```
$response ='<string xmlns="tempuri.org/">; "
    <IDV>
        <exshowroomPrice>710570</exshowroomPrice>
        <idv_amount>675042</idv_amount>
        <idv_amount_min>607537</idv_amount_min>
        <idv_amount_max>776298</idv_amount_max>
        <exshowroomPrice_min>639513</exshowroomPrice_min>
        <exshowroomPrice_max>817156</exshowroomPrice_max>
        <outputmessage></outputmessage>
        </IDV>"
</string>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response, SimpleXMLElement::class,
        LIBXML_NOERROR );
$idv = $xml->children("tempuri.org/");
echo "exshowroomPrice ".$idv->IDV->exshowroomPrice.PHP_EOL;
```

The output of which is...

```
exshowroomPrice 710570
```

Update:
As the data your getting back has the markup encoded (i.e. it comes back as `&lt;IDV&gt;` ), you need to decode it before passing it into SimpleXML...

```
$response = html_entity_decode((string)$response);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response, SimpleXMLElement::class,
        LIBXML_NOERROR );
$idv = $xml->children("http://tempuri.org/");
echo "exshowroomPrice ".$idv->IDV->exshowroomPrice.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thanks Nigel but I tried your option it didn't work. I have updated my question , you just simply copy the code and try at your end. So you can understand the exact response and issue.

Comment: I've updated the answer, it makes it so much easier when you can test it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php),

```
$xmlString = 
'<IDV>
 <exshowroomPrice>710570</exshowroomPrice>
 <idv_amount>675042</idv_amount>
 <idv_amount_min>607537</idv_amount_min>
 <idv_amount_max>776298</idv_amount_max>
 <exshowroomPrice_min>639513</exshowroomPrice_min>
 <exshowroomPrice_max>817156</exshowroomPrice_max>
 <outputmessage></outputmessage>
 </IDV>';


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

echo $xml->exshowroomPrice;
```

Comment: you can tried it your end i will provide you details  click on following link  https://asteriskcomputerclasses.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=XWjQomABAAA.1BxGDmv3zefNwD1OxqkT8zWkEULpbVCxujtB0YbePuMEvNMa5nczlTt_YYagbSvfVo_5tL7-2SDnCxPsvPUPVg.TsrW_oz6g9S4Dab_E6fwOg&postId=8289861437594885852&type=POST

Answer (score 0):

If the object is correctly created with PHP function [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

```
 $response = "
 <IDV>
 <exshowroomPrice>710570</exshowroomPrice>
 <idv_amount>675042</idv_amount>
 <idv_amount_min>607537</idv_amount_min>
 <idv_amount_max>776298</idv_amount_max>
 <exshowroomPrice_min>639513</exshowroomPrice_min>
 <exshowroomPrice_max>817156</exshowroomPrice_max>
 <outputmessage></outputmessage>
 </IDV>";

   $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

Then the object created looks like this `print_r($xml);`

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [exshowroomPrice] => 710570
    [idv_amount] => 675042
    [idv_amount_min] => 607537
    [idv_amount_max] => 776298
    [exshowroomPrice_min] => 639513
    [exshowroomPrice_max] => 817156
    [outputmessage] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )
)
```

so all you need to call/echo the attribute you need:

```
echo $xml->exshowroomPrice;
echo '<exshowroomPrice>' . $xml->exshowroomPrice . '</exshowroomPrice>';
```

that will prints:

```
 710570  
 <exshowroomPrice>710570</exshowroomPrice>
```

**[Live code on eval.in](https://eval.in/927494)**

Comment: if I inspect the code I am getting following response                                  <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    "<IDV><exshowroomPrice>710570</exshowroomPrice>
        <idv_amount>675042</idv_amount>
        <idv_amount_min>607537</idv_amount_min>
        <idv_amount_max>776298</idv_amount_max>
        <exshowroomPrice_min>639513</exshowroomPrice_min>
        <exshowroomPrice_max>817156</exshowroomPrice_max>
        <outputmessage></outputmessage>
    </IDV>"
</string>      click on url  http://pocketinfotech.com/demo/policy_test/test3.php

Comment: @arunmane If the response is wrapped in `<string>` tag then one more level `IDV` is in the object so then use `$xml->IDV->exshowroomPrice`, see it live on https://eval.in/927513

Comment: thanks but still its now working. please click on link I shred details so you can tried at your end. https://asteriskcomputerclasses.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=XWjQomABAAA.1BxGDmv3zefNwD1OxqkT8zWkEULpbVCxujtB0YbePuMEvNMa5nczlTt_YYagbSvfVo_5tL7-2SDnCxPsvPUPVg.TsrW_oz6g9S4Dab_E6fwOg&postId=8289861437594885852&type=POST

Comment: Pls, do `echo '<pre>' . print($response, true). PHP_EOL .  print_r($xml, true) . '</pre>';` on your environment and update the original question with the output.

Comment: @arunmane Add the code above to your example, run it and add the output. I need to see what exactly is printed on your side.

Comment: I have updated my question now you just simply copy code and try at your end. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First You have to check output in xml which is correct format or not using below code and if there are no error then simplexml_load_string — Interprets a string of XML into an object.

```
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc = simplexml_load_string($response);
    $xml = explode("\n", $response);
    if (!$doc) {
       $errors = libxml_get_errors();
       foreach ($errors as $error) {
           echo display_xml_error($error, $xml);
       }
      libxml_clear_errors();
    } else { 
      $note = <<<XML $response XML;
      $xml = simplexml_load_string($note);
      $xml = (array) $xml;
      echo $xml['exshowroomPrice'];
      print_r($xml);
    }
```

Comment: thank you I done above things but it not showing any out it go into else part . please check below url http://pocketinfotech.com/demo/policy_test/test3.php

Comment: <?php
$response = "<IDV><exshowroomPrice>710570</exshowroomPrice><idv_amount>675042</idv_amount><idv_amount_min>607537</idv_amount_min><idv_amount_max>776298</idv_amount_max><exshowroomPrice_min>639513</exshowroomPrice_min><exshowroomPrice_max>817156</exshowroomPrice_max><outputmessage></outputmessage></IDV>";
$note=<<<XML
$response
XML;

$xml=simplexml_load_string($note);
$xml = (array) $xml;
echo $xml['exshowroomPrice'];
//echo $xml->exshowroomPrice;
print_r($xml);
?>

Comment: it still not working i have shred you details you can try at your end.